# What purpose does an empty gif (1x1 pix) file serve?

Tags: web-server, performance, nginx

I've seen a few random pages mention using empty gif images to somehow increase performance. I've also found the nginx has a [module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpEmptyGifModule) for just this purpose. What I can't figure out, is exactly how serving this small file is supposed to boost performance or perceived responsiveness from a web server. Can anyone help me understand the benefits?

Comment: I would love to know this too. I've always seen em around but never thought to question why...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1x1 gif files are used by some websites to set spacing between elements (particularly on older websites, made when browsers' interpretations of HTML/CSS were more divergent *cough* IE *cough*

They are also used more often today as a request target for "tracking pixels", which are used as a tool for gathering usage stats, etc., especially for email/marketing campaigns.

The reason you'd provide a special module for this file is that (a) it's requested often, and (b) it returns the same thing every time, so you don't want to have to go to disk for the file if you can avoid it.

Comment: I'd always heard it was primarily for tracking users, so the shadowy "they" would embed it as a pull from another server or location for easy tracking of hits and also email it embedded in html mails to know if you read the message or not; spammer's version of read receipt on people who don't disable HTML/RTF messages and thus harvest them as successful addresses to sell to other spammers.

Comment: That's a common use in e-mail, yeah. For websites, that technique has been mostly replaced with JavaScript like Google Analytics.

Comment: Also known **Transparent.gif** , **Spacer.gif**, **Clear1x1.gif**, **Blank.gif** check wiki [Link1](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Transparent.gif) and [Link2](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blank.gif) , one of the usage with css sprites flags image in [this](https://www.flag-sprites.com/) site.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure about increasing performance, but 1x1 pixel images are commonly used in tracking.  Commonly known as a [web bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug) (or beacon), this image causes the browser to make an HTTP request to the server from which the image originates.  This request can then be examined for tracking information (e.g. IP, browser, referrer, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Doing a Google search for "[one pixel gif](http://www.google.com/search?q=one+pixel+gif)" or "[single pixel gif](http://www.google.com/search?q=single+pixel+gif)" returns many articles that discuss the technique of using that file for positioning elements of a web page.

From [Optimizing Design: One-pixel GIFs](http://www.devx.com/projectcool/Article/19937) (January 1, 2000):

> In the early days of web design, HTML limitations inspired designers to find all sorts of workarounds in order to have control over the layout of pages. One of the most significant of these workarounds was the single pixel GIF trick, using a single pixel GIF and modifying it with the height, width, hspace, and vspace attributes of the IMG tag.
>
> The GIF itself is tiny and requires virtually no download time. And, depending on whether the single pixel is transparent or not, the result can be used as a spacer, or as a horizontal or vertical rule.

Answer (score 2):

Including 1x1 images doesn't increase performance, it decreases it - it's an extra HTTP request, a small amount of extra bandwidth, etc.

That module is simply intended to make the **decrease** in performance **smaller** (by serving the image more efficiently), as the 1x1 pixel technique for positioning elements on the page can be useful.

Comment: Maybe it was a misunderstanding that the 1x1 nature of the image is optimized to do its job, whatever it might be (tracking, spacing, etc.), with the most optimal performance.

Comment: but css sprites increase performance, 1x1 images Also known **Transparent.gif** , **Spacer.gif**, **Clear1x1.gif**, **Blank.gif** check wiki [Link1](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Transparent.gif) and [Link2](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blank.gif) , one of the usage with css sprites flags image in [this](https://www.flag-sprites.com/) site.

Comment: @stom This has nothing to do with CSS sprites.

Answer (score 1):

They are also used for image spriting; a small transparent image is used as the src attribute of an image tag, and the real image is a CSS background image. The performance advantage comes from the CSS background being only part of a single image which combines many images from the page, reducing the number of overall requests.

See for example:

- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp
- http://spriteme.org/faq.php#def

Comment: This should be the leading answer.  There's lots of good info in the other answers about things that can be done with single pixel gifs, but this is the only answer which describes a performance reason for using them.

Answer (score 0):

All great answers above. There is another use for the module.

When you want to block ads from being displayed in your network, if you simply deny the URLs requested the browser load times suffer (or you get a block message displayed on the page). The solution then is to redirect browser traffic to an internal site serving a blank image (rather than deny the request URL).

Some tricks that can be used to do the redirect are [Dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) and Squid rewrite rules.